# Paginating Eloquent 4.2 models outside of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent 4.2 outside of Laravel (in a Slim 2 app) and have a Collection of Article objects (15 of them) I want to paginate using Laravels pagination library.

I've managed to set up the pagination, but can't find how to set the current page programmatically.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$articles = new Article;
$articles = $articles->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

$pagination = $articles->paginate(5);

foreach($pagination as $s) {
    dump($s);
}

dd($pagination);
```

The foreach loop produces 5 instances of Article, and the dd() produces an instance of LengthAwarePaginator.

My question is, since I can only access the data for the first page, how do I set the page to read from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very hacky way of forcing the pagination class to work outside of Laravel (since it seems to be, oddly, very tightly-coupled with the framework). This method allows you to set the current path and page number - but unfortunately doesn't allow you to use methods like links() etc. Code below:

```
Paginator::currentPathResolver(function() use($id) { return $id; });
Paginator::currentPageResolver(function() use($id) { return $id; });

$articles = new Article;
$articles = $articles->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
$pagination = $articles->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Remember to set the pagination before you execute the query

```
//as for me i am using this, and it works fine, and we have the same laravel version 4.2
\Paginator::setCurrentPage($current_page);

$pagination = $articles->paginate(5);
```

## Update

Try this then

```
$articles = new Article;
\Paginator::setCurrentPage($current_page);
//you have to use $articles->orderBy instead of $articles = $articles->orderBy
$articles->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
$pagination = $articles->paginate(5);
```

Comment: I've tried this way, this is the result: Fatal error: Call to protected method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::setCurrentPage() from context

Comment: I have again updated my answer. please check. i think i see now what your problem is.

Comment: You mention in your answer you are using Laravel - I'm not; just Eloquent. Does that matter?

Comment: That I am not sure myself. Sorry I did not understand that you were using it outside of Laravel. I have been checking the forum in laracast https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-paginator-does-not-exist-laravel-42 and it says that "Pagination uses Laravel routing. So you can't use it outside of a Laravel app." and this http://laravel.io/forum/04-28-2014-using-pagination?page=1

Answer (score 0):

A slightly mod of the answer below, for those using Illuminate Paginator with composer. Please note the LengthAwarePaginator class being called:

```
Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::currentPathResolver(function() use($page) { return "/your_path"; });
Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::currentPageResolver(function() use($page) { return $page; });
```

Also, you should get the page var:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $this->sanitize($_GET['page'], 'int') : 1);
```

Sanitize being one of my functions that scape malicious codes that may come from the URI